# MYSQL pull search data on 5 tables depend on trimmed id

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not an expert I tried to search on 4 tables which it depend on it's trimmed item id where a example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6014c/4/0

```
SELECT item.str_kd_induk_item, 
    (
        CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '1' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM buku_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '2' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM penelitian_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '3' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM majalah_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '5' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM ta_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)        
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '6' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM jurnal_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)
        END) AS judul,koleksi.str_nm_koleksi,sumber.str_nm_sumber
FROM item,sumber,koleksi WHERE koleksi.str_kd_koleksi=SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) AND sumber.int_id_sumber=item.id_sumber AND judul='%a%';
```

I couldn't search on virtual table judul, because it not recognized anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Instead of repeating the `SUBSTRING()` on every line, use `CASE SUBSTRING(...) WHEN '1' THEN ... WHEN '2' THEN ...`

Comment: Thank You verymuch Barmar, now all item diplayed correcly your solution and Gordon solution wonderfull :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use a `having` clause.  You should also learn proper explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT item.str_kd_induk_item, 
    (
        CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '1' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM buku_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '2' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM penelitian_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '3' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM majalah_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '5' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM ta_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)        
        WHEN SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item,8,1) = '6' THEN (SELECT str_judul_asli FROM jurnal_judul WHERE str_kd_judul=item.str_kd_judul)
        END) AS judul,koleksi.str_nm_koleksi,sumber.str_nm_sumber
FROM item JOIN
     sumber
     ON sumber.int_id_sumber = item.id_sumber JOIN
     koleksi
     ON koleksi.str_kd_koleksi = SUBSTRING(item.str_kd_induk_item, 8, 1)
HAVING judul = '%a%';
```

Comment: Thank You I will learn more, I think my case query also wrong, it didn't display judul correctly too :'( thank your for answering